# How to update regmodel with writes going from RTL blocks

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I understand that regmodel values are updated as soon as transaction initiates from test environment on any of the connected interfaces.

However consider a scenario:

1. RTL registers being updated from ROM on boot-up (different value than default)
2. Processor in RTL writing to register as compared to test environment.

In these 2 cases regmodel doesn't get updated/mirrored with correct RTL value. I would like to know what is correct procedure to get regmodel updated, if there is none at the moment what other approach can be taken to keep these 2 in sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case you have to pre-load your memory model with your ROM contents at the start of the simulation. There isn't any infrastructure to do this in `uvm_memory` (unfortunately), so you'll have to implement it yourself.

For the second case, you have to use a more grey-box approach to verification. You have to monitor the bus accesses that the processor does to the peripherals and update the register values based on those transactions. This should be OK to do from a maintainability point of view, because the architecture of your SoC should be pretty stable in that sense (you've already decided to use a processor so that will always be there, but you might not know which peripherals will make it to the end).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to implement second case. Monitor bus and update regmodel at correct point I think https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.1d/html/files/reg/uvm_reg_map-svh.html#uvm_reg_map.get_reg_by_offset is correct way of implementing it. However no matter what I try it seems to return NULL. I've been through http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1945-uvm-reg-map-get-reg-by-offset-is-misleading/ (guessing that's your post) even that didn't help

Comment: so get_reg_by_offset didn't work for me, instead I implemented it as register_model.map.get_registers (regs); foreach (regs[i]) if (regs[i].get_offset == (monitor_addr - base_addr)) if(write) regs[i].set (data). Sorry formatting would look really bad in comment but didn't want to write separate answer. With this approach I don't like the fact that there will be so many iterations per invocation but I think for now I'll stay with it.

Comment: @wisemonkey you can probably also modify your predictor or insert an extra TLM FIFO style component that does the subtraction of `base` address for you. This way you the expensive loops that will probably destroy your performance. Also, I think I opened a thread on the UVM forums regarding the offset thing, where it expects the absolute address instead of the offset in the register file/map/etc, You'll have to play around with the details or open up a new question with the exact problem you're facing with `get_reg_by_offset(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to understand bit more about register model from UVM and then ask question accordingly